# Conditional check constraint in Postgresql with Regex

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to create a conditional check constraint in postgresql. When a_type is 'a', I want the b to only contain digit. When a_type is not 'a', I want b to contain any characters. How would I accomplish this? I have this now:

EDIT: 
I think this should work.

```
CONSTRAINT test CHECK (a_type <> 'a' AND b ~* '^.$') OR (a_type = 'a' AND b ~* '^[0-9]+$')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to use regexp when `a_type <> 'a'`:

```
check (a_type <> 'a' or a_type = 'a' and b ~* '^[0-9]+$')
```